# Remove duplicates in Dictionary<int, List<PointF>>

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following code:

```
Dictionary<int, List<PointF>> dictEntities = new Dictionary<int, List<PointF>>();
dictEntities.Add(1, new List<PointF>() { new PointF(1.0F, 2.0F), new PointF(3.0F, 4.0F) });
dictEntities.Add(2, new List<PointF>() { new PointF(3.0F, 4.0F), new PointF(1.0F, 2.0F) });
dictEntities.Add(3, new List<PointF>() { new PointF(7.0F, 8.0F), new PointF(9.0F, 6.0F) });
```

I want to remove the dictionary entries which lists are duplicates.
Expected result after the duplicates have been removed: The dictionary now contains 2 entries (either "1" and "3" or "2" and "3") because entry 1 and 2 have the same lists of PointF's inside. 1 or 2 gets removed from the dictionary. I think I have to sort the List first then make a distinct on it somehow? But how to I actually delete the entries that are duplicates?

What I have tried so far is this:

```
foreach (var item in dictEntities.ToList())
{
    while (dictEntities.Values.Contains(item.Value))
    {
        dictEntities.Remove(item.Key);
    }
}
```

But this always empties the whole dictionary. I have to work it out somehow.

Thank you

Comment: What have you tried so far and what results are you seeing? Once you've tried something folks are happy to help but usually they want to see some effort put into it first.

Comment: Linq will not be a good fit here, it will just look like code golf. Just use a nested foreach or an actual design pattern to model your behaviors instead of the dictionary with a set of lists.

Comment: Do you always have 2 `PointF` values in your lists? If so, it looks like you would be better off with a custom class that encompasses this instead of making lists.

Comment: @DavidG No There could be any amout of PointF in the Lists.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this with a custom `IEqualityComparer` and using `GroupBy`. For example:

```
public class MyComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<PointF>>
{
    public bool Equals(List<PointF> l1, List<PointF> l2)
    {
        //If lists contain different amount of items, they are different
        if(l1.Count() != l2.Count()) return false;

        //Order the lists by X then Y, that way we can compare them in order
        var orderedL1 = l1.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y).ToList();
        var orderedL2 = l2.OrderBy(p => p.X).ThenBy(p => p.Y).ToList();

        for(var i = 0; i < l1.Count(); i++)
        {
            if(orderedL1[i].X != orderedL2[i].X) return false;
            if(orderedL1[i].Y != orderedL2[i].Y) return false;
        }

        //They must be the same if we reached here
        return true;
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<PointF> dp)
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var distinctList = dictEntities
    .GroupBy(de => de.Value, new MyComparer())
    .Select(de => de.Key);
```

If you want to keep it as a dictionary, instead of `Select`, use `ToDictionary` and take your pick of method to choose the key. Here is an example using `First` (which means you will get items 1 and 3 from your example):

```
var distinctList = dictEntities
    .GroupBy(de => de.Value, new MyComparer())
    .ToDictionary(g => g.First().Key, g => g.Key);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can you tell me how to retrieve a dictionary with your usage-example? I need the keys from the original dictionary.